# Rock Paper Scissors increasing label value on function result

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently trying to learn Javascript, and I am trying to make a simple Rock, Paper, Scissors application. At the moment my code looks like this

```js
function computerPlay() {
  let options = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'];
  return options[Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length)]
}

computerWin = 0;
userWin = 0;
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
buttons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    computerSelection = computerPlay();
    playerSelection = button.id;
    var userScore = document.getElementById('userScore');
    var computerScore = document.getElementById('computerScore');
    const result = playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);
    if (result == 1) {
      userWin++;
      userScore.nodeValue = Number(userWin);
    } else if (result == 2) {
      computerWin++;
      computerScore.nodeValue = Number(computerWin);
    }

  });
});


function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
  playerSelection = playerSelection.toLowerCase();
  computerSelection = computerSelection.toLowerCase();
  let playerWon = 1
  let computerWon = 0
  let tie = 2
  if (playerSelection == computerSelection) {
    return tie;
  }
  if (playerSelection === "rock") {
    if (computerSelection === "scissors") {
      return playerWon;
    }
    if (computerSelection === "paper") {
      return computerWon;
    }
  }
  if (playerSelection === "scissors") {
    if (computerSelection === "paper") {
      return playerWon;
    }
    if (computerSelection === "rock") {
      return computerWon;
    }
  }
  if (playerSelection === "paper") {
    if (computerSelection === "rock") {
      return playerWon;
    } else {
      return computerWon;
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<button id="rock">ROCK</button>
<button id="paper">PAPER</button>
<button id="scissors">SCISSORS</button>
<br>
<p>Vlad : </p>
<input type="text" id="userScore" value="0" />
<p>Computer : </p>
<input type="text" id="computerScore" value="0" />
```

When I press any of the buttons, the round is played, a result is returned, but the value inside the labels never changes.

Comment: What do you think **const** as in `const result` means?

Comment: `.nodeValue` should just be `.value`.

Comment: The code works fine if you just change `.nodeValue` to `.value`.

Comment: @Barmar - Yes, you're right.

Comment: @Barmar thank you, IntelliSense was always changing value to nodeValue as I was typing and I went with it, I'll read a bit more on nodeValue vs value.

Comment: Be wary of using arrow functions in event listeners. You lose the ability to use `this` to get the element triggering the event: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/when-and-why-you-should-use-es6-arrow-functions-and-when-you-shouldnt-3d851d7f0b26/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `.value` and not `.nodeValue`

[Rock Paper Scissor Video Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLE9cyLFRZmXJb3veEAzMghWtjwOY0RJZt)

```js
function computerPlay() {
  let options = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'];
  return options[Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length)]
}

computerWin = 0;
userWin = 0;
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
buttons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    computerSelection = computerPlay();
    playerSelection = button.id;
    var userScore = document.getElementById('userScore');
    var computerScore = document.getElementById('computerScore');
    const result = playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);
    if (result == 1) {
      userWin++;
      userScore.value = Number(userWin);
    } else if (result == 2) {
      computerWin++;
      computerScore.value = Number(computerWin);
    }

  });
});


function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
  playerSelection = playerSelection.toLowerCase();
  computerSelection = computerSelection.toLowerCase();
  let playerWon = 1
  let computerWon = 0
  let tie = 2
  if (playerSelection == computerSelection) {
    return tie;
  }
  if (playerSelection === "rock") {
    if (computerSelection === "scissors") {
      return playerWon;
    }
    if (computerSelection === "paper") {
      return computerWon;
    }
  }
  if (playerSelection === "scissors") {
    if (computerSelection === "paper") {
      return playerWon;
    }
    if (computerSelection === "rock") {
      return computerWon;
    }
  }
  if (playerSelection === "paper") {
    if (computerSelection === "rock") {
      return playerWon;
    } else {
      return computerWon;
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<button id="rock">ROCK</button>
<button id="paper">PAPER</button>
<button id="scissors">SCISSORS</button>
<br>
<p>Vlad : </p>
<input type="text" id="userScore" value="0" />
<p>Computer : </p>
<input type="text" id="computerScore" value="0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the value of the input.  Also, your logic for result was a little messed up.  Take a look at the following and let me know if this works for you.

```js
function computerPlay() {
  let options = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors']; 
  return options[Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length)]
}

computerWin = 0;
userWin = 0;
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
buttons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    computerSelection = computerPlay();
    playerSelection = button.id;
    
    var userScore = document.getElementById('userScore');
    var computerScore = document.getElementById('computerScore');
    const result = playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);
    
    if (result === 1) {
      userWin++;      
      userScore.value = userWin;
    } else if (result === 0) {
      computerWin++;      
      computerScore.value= computerWin;
    }else if(result === 2){
       userWin= userWin + .5;      
       userScore.value = userWin;
       computerWin=computerWin + .5;      
       computerScore.value= computerWin;
    
    
    }

  });
});


function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
  playerSelection = playerSelection.toLowerCase();
  computerSelection = computerSelection.toLowerCase();
  let playerWon = 1
  let computerWon = 0
  let tie = 2
  if (playerSelection == computerSelection) {  
    return tie;
  }else if (playerSelection === "rock") {
    if (computerSelection === "scissors") {       
      return playerWon;
    }
    if (computerSelection === "paper") {        
      return computerWon;
    }
  }else if (playerSelection === "scissors") {
    if (computerSelection === "paper") {
      return playerWon;
    }
    if (computerSelection === "rock") {
      return computerWon;
    }
  }else if (playerSelection === "paper") {
    if (computerSelection === "rock") {
      return playerWon;
    } else {
      return computerWon;
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<button id="rock">ROCK</button>
<button id="paper">PAPER</button>
<button id="scissors">SCISSORS</button>
<br>
<p>Vlad : </p>
<input type="text" id="userScore" value="0" />
<p>Computer : </p>
<input type="text" id="computerScore" value="0" />
```

Comment: Thanks, it works fine but I'm not a fan of the .5 added in case of a draw. I guess rather than having the variable 'ties' I could have simply not done anything in the case of a draw. Anyway, it was just something to get me going with Javascript, so I wouldn't put too much thought into it, but thanks for your feedback.